Cognito External Providers
I am performing login with google, apple and password. I am using aws cognito for password and social and external providers for google and apple login. When I signup with email password user created in user pool with status confirmed/unconfirmed When I try to login with google it create duplicate user with status external_provider and vice versa. When I login with google or apple i handled duplication with pre signup trigger but if i signup before then i try login with google/apple i tried to external_provider linking with existing pool user in post confirmation trigger. It only shows the linked account id in identities in external_provider user but creating duplicate user in user pool. Am I doing something wrong? or how i can handle data with duplicate users.
Thanks in advance
